# Dropwizard & Hibernate - No session currently bound to execution context

Tags: hibernate, rest, dropwizard

I think I have a fair idea what my problem is here, but have absolutely NO idea how I might fix it...

Here is how I am starting my application in dropwizard :

```
@Override
public void run(ServerConfiguration configuration, Environment environment)
{

    // Setting up the database.
    final DBIFactory factory = new DBIFactory();
    final DBI jdbi = factory.build(environment, configuration.getDataSourceFactory(), "mysql");

    //Hibernate
    final UserDAO dao = new UserDAO(hibernate.getSessionFactory());
    environment.jersey().register(new UserResource(dao));

    final TemplateHealthCheck healthCheck = new TemplateHealthCheck(configuration.getTemplate());

    environment.healthChecks().register("template", healthCheck);

    // security
    //****** Dropwizard security - custom classes ***********/
    environment.jersey().register(new AuthDynamicFeature(new BasicCredentialAuthFilter.Builder<User>()
            .setAuthenticator(new BasicAuth(dao))
            .setAuthorizer(new BasicAuthorizer())
            .setRealm("BASIC-AUTH-REALM")
            .buildAuthFilter()));
    environment.jersey().register(RolesAllowedDynamicFeature.class);
    environment.jersey().register(new AuthValueFactoryProvider.Binder<>(User.class));
}
```

Now, as you can see here, I am passing my User dao into my authenticator...
No tutorial I have seen online does this, and this is because every tutorial online uses hardcoded values instead of showing how to query the DB.

That said, here is how I am trying to authenticate...

```
public class BasicAuth implements Authenticator<BasicCredentials, User> {

UserDAO _userDAO;
final Encryption enc = new Encryption();

public BasicAuth(UserDAO dao)
{
    this._userDAO = dao;
}

@Override
public Optional<User> authenticate(BasicCredentials credentials)
        throws AuthenticationException {

    // Get the user record.
    User requestedUser = _userDAO.findOneByUsername(credentials.getUsername());

    if (requestedUser != null)
    {
        // check pw.
        if(enc.compare(credentials.getPassword(), requestedUser.getPassword())) {
            return Optional.of(requestedUser);
        }
        else {
            return Optional.empty();
        }
    }
    return Optional.empty();
}
}
```

please excuse the terrible indentation above, I pasted my code here from intelliJ and it just isn't behaving well - anyways, when I try to run this application, the authenticator tells me :

```
No session currently bound to execution context
```

Here is the kicker, I know this is only for the security aspect of this that I am getting this error, because if I remove the security lines from the Application class, and run it up, I can still hit my create user endpoints (which also use this DAO) and that works well.

So my question here really, is - Am I meant to use that dao in the authenticator? If not, how the hell am I meant to query the database?

If I am, then where am I going wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not too much time right now, but I believe you need to look into "Unit of work" annotations on DW. They bridge the jersey context to hibernate

Comment: My resource that calls this uses @UnitOfWork already - which is why I am confused about this.

Comment: I do not see any brdiging though. Just annotating the resource method won't be enough if jersey does not know about your DAOs. You need to read the last section on http://www.dropwizard.io/1.0.6/docs/manual/hibernate.html#transactional-resource-methods-outside-jersey-resources which tells you how to brdige hibernate into the jersey eco system. Keyword: UnitOfWorkAwareProxyFactory

Comment: My resources are managed by jersey though. I register them. I'm actually more fluent with spring do you think it would be a good idea to switch instead of dealing with this constantly?

Comment: @MickeyThreeSheds I really miss spring when I'm juggling with all the pointless boilerplate you need to get dropwizard to work properly...

Comment: Haha, I switched to spring in the end for this, DropWizard is just so terrible to try and get to do anything.

Answer (score 9):

First, your issue:

From the DW documentation:

> Currently creating transactions with the @UnitOfWork annotation works
>   out-of-box only for resources managed by Jersey. If you want to use it
>   outside Jersey resources, e.g. in authenticators, you should
>   instantiate your class with UnitOfWorkAwareProxyFactory.

With your code, you create an `Authenticator` but you never hook that back to the Hibernate Session. How would the `Authenticator` know when to open a new Session for the `DAO` to operate on? This is done by the `UnitOfWork` mechanism. This however only currently works for the Jersey resources and needs to be enabled for any other class that wants to participate in this.

So, fortunately the Docs gives us an exact `Authenticator` example on here: 
http://www.dropwizard.io/1.0.6/docs/manual/hibernate.html

I am not going to copy their code as I have a standalone example for you to play with:

```
 public class HibernateTest extends io.dropwizard.Application<DBConfiguration> {

    private final HibernateBundle<DBConfiguration> hibernate = new HibernateBundle<DBConfiguration>(Object.class) {
        @Override
        public DataSourceFactory getDataSourceFactory(DBConfiguration configuration) {
            return configuration.getDataSourceFactory();
        }
    };

    @Override
    public void initialize(Bootstrap<DBConfiguration> bootstrap) {
        super.initialize(bootstrap);
        bootstrap.addBundle(hibernate);
    }

    @Override
    public void run(DBConfiguration configuration, Environment environment) throws Exception {
        MyDao dao = new MyDao(hibernate.getSessionFactory());
        environment.jersey().register(new MyHelloResource(dao));


        // THIS IS ABSOLUTELY CRITICAL
        MyAuthenticator proxyAuth = new UnitOfWorkAwareProxyFactory(hibernate).create(MyAuthenticator.class, MyDao.class, dao);

        AuthDynamicFeature authDynamicFeature = new AuthDynamicFeature(
                new BasicCredentialAuthFilter.Builder<Principal>()
                    .setAuthenticator(proxyAuth)
                    .setRealm("SUPER SECRET STUFF")
                    .buildAuthFilter());

        environment.jersey().register(authDynamicFeature);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        new HibernateTest().run("server", "/home/artur/dev/repo/sandbox/src/main/resources/config/db.yaml");
    }

    @Path("test")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public static class MyHelloResource {

        private MyDao dao;

        public MyHelloResource(MyDao dao) {
            this.dao = dao;
        }

        @GET
        @Path("/test")
        @UnitOfWork
        @PermitAll
        public Response downloadFile() throws Exception {
            dao.get();
            return Response.ok().build();
        }

    }

    public static class MyAuthenticator implements Authenticator<BasicCredentials, Principal> {
        private MyDao dao;

        MyAuthenticator(MyDao dao) {
            this.dao = dao;
        }

        @Override
        @UnitOfWork
        public Optional<Principal> authenticate(BasicCredentials credentials) throws AuthenticationException {
            dao.get(); 
            return Optional.empty();
        }
    }

    public static class MyDao extends AbstractDAO<Object> {

        public MyDao(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
            super(sessionFactory);
        }

        public Object get() {
            // if not bridged to Jersey this will throw an exception due to session
            currentSession().createSQLQuery("SELECT 1;").uniqueResult();
            return new Object();
        }
    }

}
```

The above code runs a minimal DW application with an h2 db setup in memory. You will have to apply your configuration changes so that it starts (and change the server configuration file)

What this does is:

1. Create the hibernate bundle supplying the `DataSourceFactory`
2. Create the `DAO`
3. Create the `Authenticator` as a proxy
4. Wire all of it together

The important bits are:

```
MyAuthenticator proxyAuth = new UnitOfWorkAwareProxyFactory(hibernate).create(MyAuthenticator.class, MyDao.class, dao);
```

This creates a proxy for you that is aware of the `UnitOfWork` annotation. It enables the `Authenticator` to hook into the (I believe) event system that will open and close sessions on request.

You then use that proxy in your `AuthDynamicFeature`

Finally, in your `Authenticator` you must tell it to open a new Session when the authentication is executed, such as:

```
@Override
        @UnitOfWork
        public Optional<Principal> authenticate(BasicCredentials credentials) throws AuthenticationException {
            dao.get(); 
            return Optional.empty();
        }
```

Now all of this will work without an exception:

```
curl user:pass@localhost:9085/api/test/test 
Credentials are required to access this resource.
```

As for your last question:

> I'm actually more fluent with spring do you think it would be a good
>   idea to switch instead of dealing with this constantly?

I think this is mostly opinion based, but: `Spring DI` != `Jersey DI`. You essentially do the same thing with Spring, you bridge `Jersey DI` with `Spring DI` such that `jersey` can access these beans in `Spring`. However, all the `session` logic is still handled the same way. `Spring` simply takes the explicit abstraction away afaik - it creates the proxies for you already when creating the bean. So I don't think you will have many advantages with this and from personal experience, bridging Spring and Jersey is not all that easy. The dependency (`spring-jersey-bridge`) jersey advertises does not work with embedded Jetties (such as DW setups) but rather by hooking into a Servlet at startup (which you don't have). This can still work, however it requires a bit of hacking to get that setup. In my experience, guice (e.g. https://github.com/xvik/dropwizard-guicey) integrates much easier and nicer into DW and will give you the same advantages. `Guice` obviously does not do all the things that Spring does (neither does `Spring` do all the things that `Guice` does) so you may need to do your own research.

I hope this clears things up and gets you started :)

Regards,

Artur